# CosmicMind/Material Textfield's PlaceHolder over left view

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, cosmicmind

Iam using [CosmicMind / Material](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material) framework trying to put an icon on the left side of the placeholder but the place holder and the image overlay each other  here is my code

```
  Txtemail.placeholder = "EmailAdress"
    Txtemail.detail = "This EmailAdress is Not Valid"
    Txtemail.delegate = self
    Txtemail.placeholderNormalColor = Color.black
    Txtemail.placeholderActiveColor = Color.pink.base
    Txtemail.dividerNormalColor = Color.cyan.base
    Txtemail.tag=Example.Email.rawValue
    imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
    image = UIImage(named: "email.png");
    imageView.image = image;
    Txtemail.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.always
    Txtemail.leftView = imageView
```

and this is the result

[image]

[image]

what am i doing wrong ? thanks in advance

Comment: put a constraint between image and Txtemail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try not setting the frame `CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20)`.

Try this:

```
let leftView = UIImageView()
leftView.image = Icon.phone?.tint(with: Color.blue.base)

textField.leftView = leftView
textField.leftViewMode = .always
```

Also, try the [TextField Sample](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Samples/tree/master/Projects/Programmatic/TextField)